# Remove frame of UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there a way in iOS 7 to completely remove the outer frame of an `UISegmentedControl`? There should be only one rectangle in tint color for the selected segment.

Comment: I don't think so... You will probably need to subclass or make your own out of buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create three images and add them your your Image Assets.

- Blank (a transparent png of any size)
- Highlight (a png of any color and size)
- Select (a png of any color and size)

[image: Xcode Image Assets Catalog showing Blank, Highlight, and Select image sets added]

Then add this code:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blank"];
UIImage *highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Highlight"];
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Select"];
UIImage *dividerImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedControl setDividerImage:dividerImage forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image: UISegmentedControl with clear background and no frame. Selected color is blue. Highlighted color is light blue.]

Comment: I just did it the same way except that I create a 1x1 pixel imge during runtime instead of an additional asset.